# TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'parentPage[ 0 ][ $.expando ]') - jQuery

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I have this strange error on my code when i refresh a listview. Here the code

```
$("#cities_list ul li").bind("click", function () {
    var tag = "";
    jLinq.from(database)
        .equals("category", category)
        .and("city", $(this).find("h3").text())
        .select(function (data) {
        tag += "<li><a href='#'><img alt='' src='images/icon.png'><h3>" + data.name + "</h3></a></li>"
    });
    $("#places_list h2 .nitem").html($(this).find("ui-li-count").text());
    $("#places_list h2 selcity").html($(this).find("h3").text());
    $("#places_list ul").html(tag);
    $("#places_list ul").listview().listview("refresh"); // error on this line
    $.mobile.changePage("#places");
});
```

What could it be? I'm working with `jquery.mobile-1.3.1` version

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/parentpage-0-is-undefined#14737000003467273)

I hope it would help you!